# What is the correct term to describe (shares owned * share value)?

Tags: shares

A really simple question.

What is the correct term to describe (shares owned * share value) ?

I do not mean market capitalization, I mean if I as an individual person multiply shares owned * individual share value I will get a number. What is that number referred to in finance? equity? Capitalization? Something else? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Dave! Good first question. We hope you enjoy your stay here. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is typically referred to as the "market value" of your holdings--it is the revenue you would generate if you sold your holdings at that moment (less any transaction costs, of course)